# What is binary operator and why it can not be applied to Double Operands? I am getting an Error in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to do a simple math with two Double variables.
**My Codes**:

```
var a: Double = 40.0
var b: Double = 1.7

var c = a/b^Double(2)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
error: binary operator '^' cannot be applied to two 'Double' operands
var c = a/b^Double(2)
```

What is wrong here? Thank You.

Comment: The *Bitwise XOR Operator* `^` is available only for `UInt8`

Comment: What “simple math” are you trying to do? If you think you are squaring a number, you’re not.

Comment: you possibly wanted `Double(UInt8(a/b)^2)`,  welcome to swift. But that precision juijui

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to square a number, you could do the following:

```
let a: Double = 40
let b: Double = 1.7

pow(a/b, 2)
```